# Difference between the regularity of a set and the regularity of the boundary

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification

Is there some difference between the regularity of an open set and the regularity of the boundary of an open set?

I work with the definitions of Brezis (set) and Evans (boundary).

While Brezis takes an invertible function from a cylinder in $\mathbb R^N$ and aks for the boundary to be the image of the section of the cylinder where $x_N = 0$ and that the upper part of the cylinder go to the interior of the set, Evans only asks for a function $\gamma$ whose graph is the boundary and such that the set lies above it.

My guess is that there is no difference, since we can restrict Brezis' function to $\mathbb R^{N - 1}$ and then just ask that $x_N$ lies above the image, while we can extend Evans' $\gamma$ to $\gamma + x_N$. However, I'm lacking confidence on this line of thought, I feel that I'm missing something.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

The definitions in detail:

Set:

As usual, let $(x', x_N) \in \mathbb R^{N - 1} \times \mathbb R^N$, $Q_0$ be the unit circle in $\mathbb R^{N - 1}$, $Q$ be the cylinder with base $Q_0$ and height $1$ and $Q_+ = Q \cap \mathbb R_+^N$. An open set $\Omega$ is of class $C^1$ if for every $x \in \partial \Omega$ there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $\mathbb R^N$ and an invertible map $H: Q \to U$ such that
$$
H \in C^1(\overline Q), \quad H^{-1} \in C^1(\overline U), \quad H(Q_+) = U \cap \Omega, \quad H(Q_0) = U \cap \partial \Omega$.
$$

Boundary:

An open bounded set $U$ is said to have boundary of class $C^k$ if for each $x^0 \in \partial U$ there exists $r > 0$ and a $C^k$ function $\gamma: \mathbb R^{N - 1} \to \mathbb R$ such that, upon relabeling and reorienting the coordinate axes if necessary,
$$
U \cap B_r(x^0) + \{x \in B_r(x^0) \ : \ x_N > \gamma(x_1, \ldots, x_{N - 1})\}.
$$

Comment: For the question in the title - yes, there may be a difference. The set $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y \neq 0 \}$ has a smooth boundary, but the set itself is probably not regular enough for some theorems to hold. 
However, as far as I understood the precise statement, this is not exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Thanks, indeed it answers the question I had in my mind. But what exactly do you understand I'm asking? 

In my mind, I asked if the definitions are equivalent, which amounts to regularity of the boundary and of the set being the same thing? Or not?

Comment: Also, I can see why Brezis' definition's fail, but doesn't Evans' fail as well? Is there another definition for the regularity of the boundary?

Comment: OK, to be honest, I didn't fully understand the definitions you briefly described here. I had the impression that both definitions include my example, so it's not relevant. Anyway, I'm happy if this helps you!

Comment: I will improve the statement of the definitions. However, I'm now a bit in doubt if it really solves it. Clearly your example is not smooth, by Brezis' definition, but I'm not sure it has smooth boundary as Evans describe it